# How to modify raw HTML of ASP.NET page on PreRender?

Tags: asp.net

I want to access the raw HTML code that my ASP.NET System.Web.UI.Page is about to render.

How can i do that? Is there a property or method like System.Web.UI.Page.HTML or something like that.

I know I could loop through the Controls List of the page and get access to all the Literal Controls etc, but I was wondering if there's a direct property or method that can return me the raw html, which I can modify just before rendering the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, on `PreRender`, the page has not yet been `Render`'d, so there would be no HTML.

Second, look at the [`HttpResponse.Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx) property.

Comment: Yeah the page is not rendered but all the controls are ready to be rendered you can modify any control values here and it will refelect on the rendered page. for example i can get hold of asp:hyperlink and modify its navigate url property, and it will reflect on the rendered page. 

Oh i guess, since i can make changes to controls that means final html is not ready yet. Gotchaa...where can i get hold of the final html and still make changes to it before it renders?

Comment: As I said, look at the Filter property.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **HTTPModules** to make changes or just observe content inside the HTTP Pipeline.  This would allow you to do things that are not necessarily the concern of the main application. Aside from providing additional layers for your application architecture, this can be handy for injecting changes after a product has gone to production since the main application itself does not necessarily have to be made aware of the changes (although that depends on which config you register the module in).